# Select Target for Visual Studio Cross Compile - (2017 / 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, cross-compiling, target-platform

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for cross compiling to a Linux target and everything is working very well for a single target.

Now I want to add a second target and be able to select which target to use similar to targeting different mobile devices for Xamarin.

I have defined a second device with a unique I address.

[image]

Only the first one shows in the start menu and there appears to be no way of selecting the second target without **deleting** the first so that only the second one is available.

[image]

There also appears to be no way of selecting a preference in the connection manager.

The same thing is happening in VC2019 Preview.

I've tried restarting VS, even tried rebooting.

I've looked on the Microsoft web site for how to create targets (which I have done) but it doesn't mention how to select between them, or even make them both show up as available.

What am I missing?

Comment: Report to Microsoft directly, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Comment: Thanks - I will do, but wasn't sure if this is actually a bug or something I'm missing